# Getting RSA public key from PKCS1 key

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, pkcs#1

I get my public key in the below format and I need to use java to encrypt some data using this key

> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIGJAoGBAKDZp/3e4w1nJA/ImDMgaGowWfTnhlFkrvS86LBc6wh1/zBRt51/2F/o/ZzaA5mZ
>   nx5YMlhDOf3vHyzyO4KzYlG8md3RQU7eKQQDxgRfW1v0f7WVQoC2Dxbupyz0JVV4jQStYUYW
>   ifGsh76wI3rkzlq3F2Ea/+jqMxX/AZOO30tBAgMBAAE=
>   -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BouncyCastle`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) library to achieve this. Your key is in PEM fromat. To read it you can use `PEMParser` :

```
private static PublicKey readPublicKey(String path) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(path));
    Object object = pemParser.readObject();
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) object;

    RSAKeyParameters rsa = (RSAKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(subjectPublicKeyInfo);

    RSAPublicKeySpec rsaSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsa.getModulus(), rsa.getExponent());
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    return kf.generatePublic(rsaSpec);
}
```

And then to encrypt with this key :

```
PublicKey publicKey = readPublicKey("src/main/resources/key.pem");

String dataToEncrypt = "myMessage";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Tested with versions : [`bcpkix-jdk15on`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.62) and [`bcprov-jdk15on`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.62).